# Intersection of a closed hyperplane and a dense subspace of a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a dense subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. If $M$ is a closed hyperplane in $H$, then is it true that $V \cap M$ is dense in $M$?

Comment: After posting an answer here a while ago, I noticed that this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214227/intersection-of-a-hyperplane-and-a-subspace/3888127#3888127, so I moved my answer  there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection of a Hyperplane and a Subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214227/intersection-of-a-hyperplane-and-a-subspace)

Comment: Yes, the above reply does answer my question, thank you.